# Which ray-tracing software is compatible with Graphics3D?

Tags: export, graphics3d, reference-request, rendering

I am interested in working alternative to *Mathematica*'s FrontEnd for rendering `Graphics3D` produced by *Mathematica*. The requrements are:

- An ability to import `Graphics3D` objects exported from *Mathematica* in any of 3D export formats supported by *Mathematica*.
- It seems that in most cases *Mathematica*'s support of 3-rd party 3D geometry formats is incomplete (*Mathematica* does not export the complete scene description). So the second requirement is that recovering of dropped parts of the scene description would be as easy as possible.

I am most interested in rendering polygonal surfaces computed by *Mathematica* which are presented internally as `GraphicsComplex`.

It will be very appreciated if an answerer show the complete way to render some simple *Mathematica*-generated surface with several point light sources like this:

```
lightSources = {{"Point", Red, {1/2, 1, 1}}, 
                {"Point", Green, {1, 1/2, 1}}, 
                {"Point", Blue, {0, 0, 1}}};
pl = Show[
  Plot3D[Sin[x*y*Pi^2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   Lighting -> lightSources], 
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], 
    Point[lightSources[[All, 3]], 
     VertexColors -> lightSources[[All, 2]]]}]]
```

[image: plot]

---

***Related:***

- [Ray-tracing Graphics3D with UnityLink](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1801300)
- [Photorealistic Rendering: A walkthrough for working with LuxCoreRender](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1810945)

---

Comment: I would use Blender. See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4745/245)

Comment: @Jens Does `Export` to the .wrl format also exports light sources specification?

Comment: Not wrl, but x3d format does seem to work. I also tried obj but it doesn't contain the lamps. Unfortunately, in x3d the camera position isn't maintained. My feeling when I did this some time ago was that I could just as well generate the surfaces with Blender's python bindings and not use Mathematica at all for that.

Comment: @Jens Looking in the .x3d file exported from *Mathematica* (it is an `"XML"` file) I see only vertex colors for the two objects: `IndexedFaceSet` and `IndexedLineSet`. For the former all the colors are white, for the later they are black and it seemingly not necessary at all. Strangely enough, the colors of light sources are shifted by .05: it is `'0.9 0.05 0.05'` instead of `Red` for example.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, the material is white - I thought I had deleted some light sources and saw the colors still there, but I actually had only hidden the lamps in the editor, not cut them from the scene... So yes, x3d gets pretty close to a faithful export format.

Comment: @Jens In the Blender the surface get name "ShapeIndexedFaceSet" and the light sources: "TODO", "TODO.001" etc. But I still unable to change the default rendering which gives [this](http://i.imgur.com/qW3rQ.png).

Comment: I'll try to give a stepwise account later today, but it will obviously end up being more a Blender tutorial and  I can't do it right now (only have a laptop, no 3-button mouse at the moment...).

Answer (score 11):

Although exporting `x3d` format maintains the light sources and exports the mesh, it isn't perfect when used with Blender (the only 3D editor I tried). However, since it's the best solution I have, I wrote some brief instructions for that procedure. It's important to note that I used Blender version 2.60 and *Mathematica* 9.

Since the instructions are almost entirely related to Blender, they are probably not on topic here, and I'll just point you to the web page where I write the information down together with some screen shots of the interactive interface, because the steps are too hard to explain in words:

**[Processing Mathematica 3D graphics in Blender](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/Mathematica/BlenderFromMMA.html)**

In principle you could export as `obj`, too, and re-create the light sources in Blender because you might well end up editing them anyway, even with the above approach, since the lighting in Blender will look so different from that in *Mathematica*.

Comment: In version 11 at least, X3D does not seem to maintain the light sources.  When I tried, it simply inserted the default light sources, even though I set them to something else than the default.

Comment: @Szabolcs You're right, I just checked it again and get the same light sources no matter what I do. I can't be sure now if it ever really worked, since I no longer have the old *Mathematica* version. I'll leave this answer up since it may still be useful for the other points raised in the question, but light sources are definitely a valid concern that I don't have a solution for...

Answer (score 8):

Here you can find some software to convert Mathematica graphics for input into POVray (untested and rather old, though)

http://www.mathconsult.ch/showroom/pubs/MathProg/htmls/2-11.htm

**Edit**
Maeder's book and files aren't available for online downloading (you've to purchase the book)

**Edit** Or perhaps you can find them at the link provided in the commen

**Edit**

Mathematica can export to pov format, and it works quite well. However, you need to add the light source manually, which is not difficult.

Here is the plot I get using pov-ray

[image]

Steps I used:

1. Export to pov using `Export["p1.pov",p1]`
2. Edit the light source. I replaced the original light source to

   light_source{ <0.5, 1, 1>  color Red}
   light_source{<1, 1/2, 1>  color Green}
   light_source{<0, 0 ,1> color Blue}
3. Remove the default setting for texture

   finish {ambient color rgb 1}
   pigment {color rgb <1, 1, 1>}

and changed it to

```
#default {
  texture {
    pigment {rgb 1}
    finish {
      ambient 0.0
      diffuse 0.6
      specular 0.6 roughness 0.001
      reflection { 0.0 1.0 fresnel on }
      conserve_energy
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When trying to download the files, I get: "The file you requested is not part of the Mathematica Programmer Web Site. It is available only on the Mathematica Programmer CD-ROM that comes with the book."

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It's Maeder's book, of course

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It seems to be here: [http://www.mathconsult.ch/showroom/ray/index.html](http://www.mathconsult.ch/showroom/ray/index.html)

Comment: @belisarius hope you don't mind the edit. I'm learning rendering using povray and I think it may benefit future reader.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Not at all. In fact my answer was more a bibliographical reference than a hands-on one. It's great to have an actual confirmation that the think works. Thanks!