# Advanced graphics with Mathematica

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, reference-request

Ten years ago I bought a book by Tom Wickham-Jones, [*Mathematica Graphics: Techniques and Applications*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98771/advanced-graphics-with-mathematica). I read parts of it but then I forgot its existance.

In recent years I read the nice book of Roozbah Hazrat, [*Mathematica: A Problem Centered Approach*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sZ9GAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=hazrat%20mathematica&source=bl&ots=jl8_Y2NEn0&sig=J_TCsgFsf82EY8P4vQ_BvhtjxuE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBmoVChMIy6bIqvaDyQIVSKUeCh3ihwyr#v=onepage&q=hazrat%20mathematica&f=false), which introduced me in the new (then) capabilities of Mathematica (introduced in version 7).

I consider my self capable to create basic graphing with Mathematica but far away from taking full advance of its amazing capabilities.

Seeing all these fantastic responses I got in my graphics-related questions I would like to collect here notebooks, tutorials or other related staff regarding advanced graphics with Mathematica.
Of course the starting point should be the Documentation Center but still there are other sources.

If my reputation does not permit to open such a general topic it could remain as an advice-type thread.

I look forward to seeing your sugestions.

1) Creating and Post-Processing Mathematica Graphics on Mac OS X
http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html

2) Visualization and Graphics
http://www.johnboccio.com/MathematicaTutorials/12_VisualizationAndGraphics.pdf

3) GRAPH DRAWING
http://www.johnboccio.com/MathematicaTutorials/10_GraphDrawing.pdf

**EDIT**

I add some useful links and related staff.
4) [Wolfram Training](https://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/vis422.html)

5) [Graphics with Mathematica](http://www.emeacollege.ac.in/bmebf/pdfs/Chapter%2012.pdf)

6) [PLOTTING AND GRAPHICS
OPTIONS IN MATHEMATICA](http://www.luc.edu/faculty/dslavsk/courses/phys301/classnotes/Plotting.pdf)

7) [Graphics with Mathematica: Fractals, Julia Sets, Patterns and Natural Forms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/044451760X)

**EDIT 2**
A new book
[Mathematica Graphics Example Book for Beginners](http://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=9240)

Comment: I've always found exciting the idea of combining mathematica output with decent rendering, see e.g. here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72899/mathematica-and-pov-ray-workflow-qa

Comment: There is a broader question [**here**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/193), and in any case you should consider setting this one as community wiki because (among other things)  there is no reasonable way to objectively  select a "best answer"

Comment: How to set it as community wiki?

Comment: To ensure that you get the latest version of Mathematica Tutorials use the [Tutorial Collection web site](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/).

Comment: Book: Michael Trott, *The Mathematica GuideBook for Graphics* (includes DVD). A bit dated but still very useful.

Comment: If you get the Trott book with the DVD, it comes with notebooks of all four volumes, which are IMO worth the price of admission and then some. If your copy doesn't come with a DVD, the notebooks are available on the publisher's website.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the suggestion about Trott's books.

Comment: Where can one buy Trott's book on Graphics for a reasonable price? I have been waiting literally for a year Amazon to get it back on stock (they somehow managed to ship the only copy they had available to a black hole before this).

Comment: Hi. According to http://www.amazon.com/Mathematica-GuideBook-Graphics-Michael-Trott/dp/1461264413 there are still available copies. You could also try bookfinder.com

Comment: @dimitris Thanks! Strangely enough my amazon.de tracking has been insistent on claiming there are no copies of reasonable price anywhere, but when I took a look now... there are aplenty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other related sources:

1) [Overview of Basic Graphics 
Commands](http://bmia.bmt.tue.nl/Software/Downloads/Campus/graphicswithmathematica.pdf#page=1&zoom=auto,-64,848)

2) [Animating Mathematica graphics inside PDF using LATEX
animate package](http://12000.org/my_notes/Mathematica_animation_into_PDF_using_latex/index.pdf)

3) [Graphics Programming](http://www.tlu.ee/~tonu/Mathematica/GraphicsProgramming%20.pdf)

4) [Various Functions of Mathematica 
about the knot theory](http://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~macky/topcomp/kiriu.pdf)

5) [LATEX labels in Mathematica plots](http://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb29-1/tb91grosse.pdf)

6) [Graphics Editing Outside of Mathematica](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v5i4/columns/andre/57-63andre.mj.pdf)

7) [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu/)

8) http://dydmat.mimuw.edu.pl/sites/default/files/wyklady/mathematica.pdf

9) [ILLUSTRATING MATHEMATICS USING 3D PRINTERS](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/3dprinter/documents/trieste.pdf)

9) http://www.bugman123.com/Math/

Answer (score 7):

1) Simply amazing:
http://intothecontinuum.tumblr.com/tagged/Mathematica

2) Jeff Bryant:
http://members.wolfram.com/jeffb/visualization/3d.shtml

3) http://vqm.uni-graz.at/notebooks/index.html

4) http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/~kraus/LiveGraphics3D/tutorial/tutorial.html#Basic%20Graphics

5) http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~ma155f/Handouts/index.html

6) http://mathvis.academic.wlu.edu/category/mathematica/