# Printing graphics files on a 3D printer

Tags: graphics, 3d-printing

What is the easiest way to have a 3D graphics of a surface created by *Mathematica* printed on a 3D printer?

Comment: Just google "mathematica 3d printing" to get started, you'll find that you can export graphics to file formats that are readable by 3d printers.  [This page](http://www.segerman.org/3d_printing_notes.html) looks like a good place to get started

Comment: Also there is a [question on advanced graphics here on mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98771/advanced-graphics-with-mathematica/99323#99323). One answer there includes [this paper on 3D-printable-formats and mathematica](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/3dprinter/documents/trieste.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

You could export it in one of the formats supported by the printer.

For example:

```
g = Graphics3D[Ball[]];

Export["ball.stl", g]
```