# How to use the POVRayRender package?

Tags: graphics3d, packages

I have downloaded the POVRayRender package and I tried to use it.
I can't get it to work.
I even used the command `Deep` instead of `Short`, that works but I can't get colors in the POV-Ray output.
Can someone explain it to me in detail from the beginning?
Mathematica and POV-Ray 3.7 are both on my `D:\` drive
I would be very happy.

Comment: Would be nice to link to source at least. Is there any manual? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you mean the package from this source: https://github.com/xslittlegrass/POVRayRender-For-Mathematica and presented in this thread: [Mathematica and POV-Ray workflow (Q&A)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72899/mathematica-and-pov-ray-workflow-qa?noredirect=1&lq=1), 
here is a small introduction:

1. Download the package to a directory of your liking and unzip.
2. Open Mathematica
3. Under File > Install... , choose package and input the path to the package you just downloaded.
4. Also copy the directory "POVRayRender" into the `$UserBaseDirectory`, which is usually on Windows: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica
5. Restart Mathematica.
6. Load the functions via: Needs["POVRayRender`"]
7. Set the path to your povray installation with, for example:

   `ConfigurePOVRayRender["POVRayPath" -> "C:\\Program Files\\POV-Ray\\v3.7\\bin\\pvengine.exe"];`
8. Try out a nice example:

   `p = ParametricPlot3D[{{4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 4 + Sin[v]}, {8 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 3 + Sin[v], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u]}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, PlotPoints -> 80, Mesh -> None];
   POVRayRender[p, Method -> "Triangle"]`

Comment: Thank you!.it works fine now,i am really happy now.