# 3D plots like in MuPAD

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

The finest 3D surface plots I've seen so far were created with MuPAD, which has been discontinued for many years unfortunately. Here's an example:
[image: 3D plot from MuPad]

How can I achieve similar results with Mathematica? I care about the quality of the surface shading. The contour plot on the bottom isn't relevant here.

Comment: You could try [POVRay](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72899/mathematica-and-pov-ray-workflow-qa).

Comment: Can you please provide the equation of this surface in MA format.

Comment: That's true, MuPAD's graphics defaults were quite nice. (The rest was quite inefficient and unwieldy, though.) In Mathematica, you can add specular effects by injecting `Specularity` directives though the `PlotStyle` option into `Plot3D`. The plot shown above contains also several (white) light sources. These can be set through the option `Lighting`.

Comment: mupad was not discontinued. It was bought by Mathworks. (after Mathworks stopped using Maple as its math symbolic engine). I still use it from time to time from inside Matlab. as was mentioned above, it might have good graphics, but it is not too strong in other areas as integration and differential equations. see for example how it did against Mathematica and others in integration tests [here](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/CAS_integration_tests/reports/rubi_49_maple_2016_mma_11_mupad_7/index.htm)

Comment: Just for reference, [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) gives very nice results too. See e.g. [this](http://asy.marris.fr/asymptote/Surfaces_3D/index.html) or [this](http://asy.marris.fr/asymptote/Surfaces_3D/fig_sa03_011208_surface.png).

Answer (score 14):

Not exactly, but maybe a good start

```
xmx = 1;
CoolColor[ z_ ] := RGBColor[z, 1 - z, 1];
f = x^3 - 3 x y^2;
surf = Plot3D[f, {x, -xmx, xmx}, {y, -xmx, xmx}, AspectRatio -> 0.8, 
   PlotRange -> {-xmx, xmx} , PlotPoints -> 50, ClippingStyle -> None,
    Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 100]], 
   ColorFunction -> CoolColor, Lighting -> {None, "Directional"}];
slice = SliceContourPlot3D[f - xmx, 
   z == -xmx, {x, -xmx, xmx}, {y, -xmx, xmx}, {z, -xmx, xmx}, 
   Contours -> 16, ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> Red];
Show[surf, slice, Axes -> {False, False, False}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Playing with other parameters and adding the [antialiasing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198/antialiasing-in-3d/200) I got the following

```
surf = Plot3D[f, {x, -xmx, xmx}, {y, -xmx, xmx}, AspectRatio -> 0.9, 
    PlotRange -> {-xmx, xmx}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
    ClippingStyle -> None, Mesh -> 20, 
    ColorFunction -> (Directive[Specularity[0.5, 20], Glow@CoolColor[#]] &), 
    Lighting -> {{"Spot", White, Scaled[{r Cos[p] Sin[t], r Sin[p] Sin[t], r Cos[t]}], a}}, 
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"] /. {r -> 0.7, p -> 4, t -> 0.4, a -> 0.75};
slice = SliceContourPlot3D[f - xmx, 
   z == -xmx, {x, -xmx, xmx}, {y, -xmx, xmx}, {z, -xmx, xmx}, 
   Contours -> 16, ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> Red];
gr = Show[surf, slice, Axes -> {False, False, False}, 
  ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's a start! Somehow the MuPAD one looks even more glossy. I don't know what it is, sharper specularity, more diffuse shading, several light sources??

Comment: @user55344 I think they have indeed 3 light sources. I've used only one.

Comment: @user55344 In v12.3 `Lighting ->"ThreePoint"` is introduced.